# How can I solve this error that occurs when I try to sort a nested list based on another nested?

Tags: python, list

I tried to base my solutions on other questions asked here but they dont quite work.

I have a nested list:

```
s = [[[921, 640], [4007, 49], [4821, 40]],
     [[1270, 20], [1943, 393], [4821, 183]],
     [[1300, 95], [857, 641], [4821, 83]]]
```

I want to sort the values at index 0 in the nested based on the values of another nested list.
The other list looks like this:

```
i = [[921, 4281, 4007], [1943, 1270, 4821], [4821, 1300, 857]]
```

As you can see the values of the sublists in `i` align with values at index 0 in the sublists of `s`, but they are not same order. Now I want to order the values in `s` based on the values in `i` like this:

```
s_new = [[[921, 640],[4821, 40], [4007, 49]],
        [[1943, 393],[1270, 20], [4821, 183]],
        [[4821, 83],[1300, 95], [857, 641]]]
```

I tried this code based other questions with similar answers:

```
s_new = [(sorted(x, key=lambda item: i.index(item[0]))) for x in s]
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: 921 is not in list
```

What am I doing wrong and why am I getting this error?

I asked this question yesterday but it got marked as duplicate. However the linked questions and answers couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: You get this error because the number 921 is not in `i` but in `i[0]`. As the doc says :     `index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value. Raises ValueError if the value is not present.`

Comment: In general, if you have a question and it is closed, try to get it reopened. We don't want duplicate questions on the platform, so creating a new one creates yet another duplicate for (volunteer) curators to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a nested level, you can do this:

```
s = [[[921, 640], [4007, 49], [4821, 40]],
     [[1270, 20], [1943, 393], [4821, 183]],
     [[1300, 95], [857, 641], [4821, 83]]]

i = [[921, 4821, 4007], [1943, 1270, 4821], [4821, 1300, 857]]

s_new = [(sorted(x, key=lambda item: i[j].index(item[0]))) for j, x in enumerate(s)]

for x in s_new:
    print(x)
```

**Output**

```
[[921, 640], [4821, 40], [4007, 49]]
[[1943, 393], [1270, 20], [4821, 183]]
[[4821, 83], [1300, 95], [857, 641]]
```

Also note that the `i` from your example is `4821` instead of `4281`. As an alternative you could iterate in parallel over the two list using zip:

```
s_new = [sorted(si, key=lambda x: ij.index(x[0])) for si, ij in zip(s, i)]
```

The two approaches above are `O(n*n)` due to the index call, for longer list is better to use a lookup dictionary, for example:

```
def sort(ls, order):
    priority = {k: p for p, k in enumerate(order)}
    return sorted(ls, key=lambda x: priority[x[0]])


s_new = [sort(si, ij) for si, ij in zip(s, i)]
```

Using a dictionary makes it `O(n log n)` that is the cost of a standard sorting algorithm.

Comment: Thank you @Dani Mesejo. Great answer with in-depth explanation. I couldnt wrap my head around it, but your answer cleared a lot of things up!

Comment: @gython Glad I could help :)